# My Jquery animation is not working, nothing is showing up

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, effect

```
$("#run_anim").click(function(){
  var box = $('.anim_box')
  box.show()
  //going to add more this is just for testing
})
```

On my site ([torin.eschweb.com](http://torin.eschweb.com)) I am trying to make an animation and so far all I have is the part to make the div show when you press the button but nothing is showing up.

Comment: It seems that you may have changed the content of the URL you included in the question. Visiting http://torin.eschweb.com/ showed a form with two inputs. I see no "animation" here and as to what code failed in comparison with the answer you were given and accepted. The question is unclear in that respect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please wrap adding event listener to a jQuery [ready method](https://api.jquery.com/ready/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#run_anim").click(function(){
    var box = $('.anim_box')
    box.show()
    //going to add more this is just for testing
  });
});
```